# How to use Enum.valueOf from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, enums, existential-type

I need to get a Java enum value from a string given Enum's Class instance. I tried code like below, but I'm getting "unbound wildcard type" compilation error. Seems, I need to do something with existential types, forSome {} or something, but I can't get how to do it right.

```
val paramClass = method.getParameterTypes()(0)
val value = paramClass match {
  case _ if classOf[Enum[_]].isAssignableFrom(paramClass) => Enum.valueOf[_ <: Enum[_]](paramClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: Enum[_]]], "MYENUM")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, tough one. I have a working solution, but I find it ugly. I'll be interested in any more elegant approach!

```
def enumValueOf[T <: Enum[T]](cls: Class[_], stringValue: String): Enum[_] =
  Enum.valueOf(cls.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], stringValue).asInstanceOf[Enum[_]]

val value = paramClass match {
  case _ if classOf[Enum[_]].isAssignableFrom(paramClass) => enumValueOf(paramClass, "MYENUM")
  case _ => // other cases
}
```

The reason why I *think* we need this complexity…

We need the compiler to believe that the `Class[_]` we have is actually a `Class[T <: Enum[T]]` (so of course, a preliminary test that this is indeed a Java enum — as done in your code — is needed). So we cast `cls` to `Class[T]`, where `T` was inferred by the compiler to be `<: Enum[T]`. But the compiler still has to find a suitable `T`, and defaults to `Nothing` here. So, as far as the compiler is concerned, `cls.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]` is a `Class[Nothing]`. This is *temporarily OK* since it can be used to call `Enum.valueOf` — the problem is that the inferred return type of `valueOf` is then, naturally, `Nothing` as well. And here we have a problem, because the compiler will insert an exception when we try to actually use an instance of type `Nothing`. So, we finally cast the return value of `valueOf` to an `Enum[_]`.

The trick is then to always let the compiler infer the type argument to `enumValueOf` and never try to specify it ourselves (since we're not supposed to know it anyway) — and thus to extract the call to `Enum.valueOf` in another method, giving the compiler a chance to bind a `T <: Enum[T]`.

As I said, I'm not very happy with this solution, which looks way more complicated than it should be…

**Update:** I've simplified the code slightly.